# Collapse/Expand caret icon changing for all items instead of just one

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

In my angular 2 app i am using a collapsing and expanding menu and based on if an item is expanded or not the icon gets toggled. Currently when i expand a menu item the icon toggles and changes correctly but it is also changing for all menu items that are not expanded.

How can i ensure that the icon css toggle only occurs for the clicked menu item. Also how can i ensure that the previous expanded item is also collapsed before expanding the new item. So only one menu item expanded at a time.

Here is my Html which is part of a for loop:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" [attr.aria-controls]="itemType.id" [attr.data-target]="'#'+itemType.id" (click)="toggleCollapse()">
    <span>{{itemType.name}}</span>
    <span class="win-icon" [ngClass]="collapse == 'open' ? 'win-icon-ChevronDown':'win-icon-ChevronLeft'"></span>
</a>

<ul [id]="itemType.id" data-toggle="buttons">
    <li class="btn" routerLinkActive="active">
        <input type="radio">
            <span (click)="...">
                item 1
            </span>
    </li>
    [...]
</ul>
```

In my component:

```
public collapse: string = "closed";

public toggleCollapse() {
    this.collapse = this.collapse == "open" ? 'closed' : 'open';
}
```

Comment: you defined (click)="toggleCollapse()" for all items so it will trigger for all items, you should sent item id for example toggleCollapse(item.id) in and in toggleCollapse get the current id and change it.

Comment: @fatemefazli what do u mean in toggleCollapse get the current id and change it? I get passing it in but how can i manipulate it to use it in the html?

Comment: if you make an stackblitz will be good and editable.

Comment: @bluePearl, if you call to toggleCollapsed as (click)=togleCollapsed(i), you can equal a variable "index" to the argument and use [ngClass]="{'win-icon-chevronDown':index==i,'win-icon-Chevron-left',index!=i}")

Answer (score 0):

Toggling using this.collapse will chage the state of all the items. Instead, you can use a temp property in itemType like, itemType.collapse.
And, looping the main array to make its collapse property true, for collapsing all other items when the current one is opened.

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" [attr.aria-controls]="itemType.id" [attr.data-target]="'#'+itemType.id"
    (click)="toggleCollapse(itemType, itemsArr)">
     <span>{{itemType.name}}</span>
     <span class="win-icon" [ngClass]="!itemType.collapse ? 'win-icon-ChevronDown':'win-icon-ChevronLeft'"></span>
```

In Component:

```
public toggleCollapse(itemType, itemsArr) {
    itemsArr.forEach((itemType) => {itemType.collapse = true; }); // for making all other items collapsed when the current one is opened
    itemType.collapse = !itemType.collapse;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But i am not sure if this really ensures that all other items are collapsed when one is expanded. At least i didn't get that feature to work and the icon is not changing properly.

Comment: It will be helpful if you can attach a working sample.